# How to speed up HSQLDB UPDATE from SELECT?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-update, hsqldb

I need to set the value in my primary table from a lookup table like this:

```
UPDATE primary
SET primary.value =
  (SELECT lookup.value FROM lookup WHERE primary.key = lookup.key)
```

The key field is a VARCHAR field in both tables and has an index in the primary table and a unique index in the lookup table.

The both tables have in the range of about 10 million rows.

This takes an incredibly long time with HSQLDB 2.3  on a fast server with 12 cores and with 15G of heapspace allocated.

What things should I know to speed this operation up as much as possible? Is there anything that I could be doing massively wrong so that performance could suffer badly? Does the maximum size of the involved VARCHAR key field have any serious impact?

I have seen that there are, in theory, alternative ways how to do this in SQL of which people have claimed they are much faster, but HSQLDB does not seem to support any of those.

Comment: what is "incredibly long"?

Comment: Please post the defined indexes on the tables involved. Did you try the `MERGE` statement? You can do a join there.

Comment: And the actual question is: why are you doing that update in the first place? If `primary.key` reference the `lookup` table you can always join the `lookup` table in your queries. As far as I can tell you are actually duplicating data referenced by foreign key.

Comment: There is a non-unique key on primary.value and a unique key on lookup.value
The reason why I want to do this is that I eventually need a table for fast access which is de-normalized. In other words, I want to be able to look up all the information I need by retrieving one single row from one single table (once that table is finished, it will not be updated any more, so no normalization is needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer one:

What you are actually doing is: dispatching 10 million (sub-) selects to the database (at least in most DB Systems). I dont know the real needs behind this, but I would try to solve this with something like a EXPORT/LOAD Table in batch

answer two:

You probably get a terrific Locking and logging (LOGFILE) problem.  again: I would try this with something like a EXPORT/LOAD Table in batch

EDIT: EXPORT/IMPORT - I dont know (your needed) syntax, the basics

```
EXPORT 
  select -needed fields- 
  from 
      primary, lookup
  where
      primary.key = lookup.key -- this will be fast


IMPORT into primary pevios EXPORT
```

edit:
 try somthing like 'Lock Table in exclusive mode' bofore starting your update

Comment: Thank you that is a great idea for working around my problem! It is just a bit hard to believe that HSQLDB really does not have anything to offer to actually update a table efficiently. I seriously doubt my decision to use HSQLDB already. As I said, I would normally do this without a subselect using proper JOIN syntax, but HSQLDB does not seem to support that (although I am not sure if there is not some other way to achieve this)

Comment: @Johsm Its not realy a DB (system) prob; while I write that, try somthing like 'Lock Table in exclusive mode' bofore starting your update

Comment: I am actually using a couple of statements which supposedly should speed up things: autocommit off, no files log, NIO size increased, transaction control MVCC, but that did not really help much. 

Concerning your suggestion I think it may be even faster to just create a new "primary" table directly, using insert  INSERT INTO newprimary (fields) SELECT fields FROM primary, lookup WHERE ...

Comment: @Johsm (again i dont know your environment) try something like that: create table primary_next, insert into primary_next, drop primary, rename primary_next to primary; if it is possible in you environment

Comment: "*dispatching 10 million (sub-) selects*" no DBMS with a decent optimizer would do that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I agree and I originally would have expected HSQLDB to have an optimizer that does not allow that. Seems I was wrong though. 
The problem is that unless you actually tried it you wont know just from the documentation or the internet how a specific software deals with this.

Comment: @Johsm: did you try the `merge` statement instead?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tested merge (with a subset) and it is unfortunately exactly as slow as the original while the insert into a new table is about 10 times faster!

Comment: You are wrong about the optimizer. The db returns only one row in the subselect using index lookup on the lookup.key. The update takes so long because the OP is trying to update a very large table and the subselect is performed 10 million times.

Comment: The basic issue here is that HSQLDB is just extremely slow on updates. The subselect does not actually contribute much to the slowness: a similar query where instead of the result of a subselect another field of the same table is taken is practically equally slow. With large updates, HSQLDB may also run out of memory. 
Because of all this I have given up on HSQLDB completely and am using H2 now which is much faster and works much better.